# Generically changing variables with listeners

Tags: java, listener, function-pointers

I have a set of instances of a class named `Marker` that has a `Marker#setDelay(double)` method. This method is called based on mouse drags (you can drag around the markers). Every marker has a corresponding `double` variable in a config class.

**I want to synchronize the config class with the marker instances. So whenever the `Marker#setDelay(double)` method is called, the corresponding variable in the config class should change too. How can I do that?**

I tried using Runnables that I can apply to the markers, so the runnable would be called from within the `Marker#setDelay(double)` method, but this Runnable does not have access to the delay value. Is there some sort of method pointer workarround?

My last resort would be a `interface` and anonymous instances for every marker. But that seems kind of ugly...

Comment: What about a Marker#getDelay() to get the value?

Comment: Why don't you post the code

Comment: @Burkhard I don't have access to the markers from within the config class. But both are created at the same place, so they can be "linked" there.

Comment: @naveejr I feel that I have explained the situation well. Do you think that adding code segments would improve the question? If you do, I will add some code. Though I will not add an SSCCE because that would blow up the question unnecessarily due to the GUI stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general off-the-shelf pattern here is straightforward: Introduce an interface like `MarkerListener`. Then you can create a (possibly anonymous) `MarkerListener` implementation that updates your config, and add it to the respective `Marker´.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

interface MarkerListener
{
    void delayChanged(double oldDelay, double newDelay);
}

class Marker
{
    private double delay;

    private final List<MarkerListener> markerListeners = 
        new CopyOnWriteArrayList<MarkerListener>();

    void addMarkerListener(MarkerListener markerListener)
    {
        markerListeners.add(markerListener);
    }

    void removeMarkerListener(MarkerListener markerListener)
    {
        markerListeners.add(markerListener);
    }

    void setDelay(double newDelay)
    {
        if (newDelay != this.delay)
        {
            double oldDelay = this.delay;
            this.delay = newDelay;
            fireDelayChanged(oldDelay, newDelay);
        }

    }

    private void fireDelayChanged(double oldDelay, double newDelay)
    {
        for (MarkerListener markerListener : markerListeners)
        {
            markerListener.delayChanged(oldDelay, newDelay);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this involves some code bloat. It is basically a minimalistic implementation of something that could also be achieved when using the `DoubleProperty` from JavaFX that Joop Eggen referred to in his answer. So you might want to consider using the `DoubleProperty`. (One could also solve this with `PropertyChangeListeners`, but these are probably not so appropriate here)

Since you referred to "function pointers": You could also use [DoubleConsumer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleConsumer.html) instances instead of introducing an own interface. But it's impossible to tell from the question whether this is the best solution here.

Comment: you are fast and it seems a complete solution for the problem

Comment: So it seems that all of the answers so far suggest using the interface approach. Your solution is actually exactly what I had in mind with my last paragraph. Also thanks for the mentioning of `DoubleConsumer`, that seems interesting. In this case though, I will use my own interface. If I was using JavaFX, Joop Eggen's solution would be pretty cool, but I am stuck with Swing on this one... ;)

Comment: I just saw that you used the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, so thanks for that too, I didn't know about that one, very cool for rarely mutated lists that need to be thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX has ...Property classes, which you can bind to receive change notifications. That is a much underestimated/overseen UI functionality.

So use a [DoubleProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/DoubleProperty.html). (A warning: the javadoc does not easily suffice for usage.)
See for a usage [here](http://patrickmoule.net/2013/01/20/notifications-when-working-with-javafx-properties/).

- Have a DoubleProperty
- addListener new ChangeListener with as ObservableValue the DoubleProperty

Comment: Wow, that is very cool. Too bad I am not using JavaFX (not yet at least). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As of Java 7 they are available in Java SE, and one does not need doing GUI. A bit of propaganda: The javafx.beans classes simplify doing MVC on the GUI as for instance a BooleanProperty of the checkbox can be helt in the model. Add to that the transition effects and CSS styling, and JavaFX is worthwile.

Comment: I know it is worthwhile and I use it for all my new projects, but this one is stuck with Java 6 unfortunately... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully understand the problem. 
Here is my solution anyway

Create a Listener

```
public interface MarkerChangeListener{
      void markerChanged(double value);
}
```

Implement the Config Class with listener

```
    public class Config implements MarkerChangeListener{

        private double delay;

        @override
        public void markerChanged(double value){
             this.delay = value;
         }

         .... 

   }
```

Add a method to your Marker class to add listener and fire the listener when the value updated

```
    public class Marker{

    private MarkerChangeListener listener;

    public void addListener(MarkerChangerListener listener){

         this.listener = listener;

    }

    public void setDelay(double delay){
    this.delay = delay;
    listener.markerChanged(delay)
    }

}
```

Add the listener to the Marker class from where you create markers.

```
marker.addListener(config);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is almost what I meant with my last paragraph (using the interface). Although I can not implement the interface in the config class but need to create an anonymous instance of the interface for every marker/variable pair and add those interfaces to the corresponding markers.